# How to reload Django context from JavaScript w/out redirect?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, bookmarks

I am developing a dictionary application and a simple bookmark page where bookmarked definitions are displayed. I am using JavaScript to add/remove a definition to/from bookmarks through a button.

The button works. However, when I am on the bookmarks page and I press it to remove a definition from my bookmarks, the definition stays there until I reload the page. I would like the definition to disappear as soon as I hit the button through JavaScript.

I tried to remove the parentNode of my button (the div for definition) but it looks horrible, and that's not what I am looking for.

I am now trying to send an AJAX request to my Django bookmarks view to re-load the context, but so far I haven't been able to do it. Can anybody help?

Here is my Javascript code (the ? is where I am stuck):

```
function toggleBookmark(event) {

    // Get definition id.
    let id = event.target.id.split("-")[1];

    // Send AJAX request to bookmark view.
    $.get("/bookmarks/bookmark/" + id, function (data) {
        if (data.added) {
            alert('Definition added to your bookmarks.')
            event.target.innerHTML = 'Remove definition from your Bookmark';
        } else if (data.removed) {
            alert('Definition removed from your bookmarks.')
            event.target.innerHTML = 'Add definition to your Bookmarks';
        }
    });

    // Send AJAX request to reload bookmarks.
    $.get("/bookmarks/", () => {
        ?
    });
}

$(window).on("load", () => {
    $(".bookmark-btn").each(function (index) {
        $(this).on("click", toggleBookmark);
    });
});
```

And here are my views:

```
class BookmarksView(generic.ListView):
    """TODO"""
    model = Definition
    template_name = "bookmarks/bookmarks.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        language = get_language()
        bookmarks = self.model.objects.filter(language=language, is_bookmarked=True)

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["bookmarks"] = bookmarks.order_by("-publication_date")
        return context


def bookmark(request, definition_id):
    """Toggle bookmarks."""
    try:
        if request.method == "GET":
            definition = Definition.objects.get(pk=definition_id)
            user = request.user
            if definition.is_bookmarked:
                # Remove bookmark.
                bookmark = Bookmark.objects.get(definition=definition)
                bookmark.delete()
                definition.is_bookmarked = False
                definition.save()
                return JsonResponse({"removed": True})
            else:
                # add bookmark.
                bookmark = Bookmark.objects.create(user=user, definition=definition)
                bookmark.save()
                user.user_bookmarks.add(bookmark)
                definition.is_bookmarked = True
                definition.save()
                return JsonResponse({"added": True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"data": False})
    except:
        return JsonResponse({"data": False})
```

Here are my URLs:

```
bookmarks_patterns = ([
    path("bookmarks/", bookmarks_views.BookmarksView.as_view(), name="bookmarks"),
    path("bookmarks/bookmark/<int:definition_id>", bookmarks_views.bookmark, name="bookmark"),
])
```

And my HTML for the bookmarks page:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
    {% for definition in definitions %}
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                    <a href="{% url 'dictionary:expression' definition.expression.slug %}">
                        {{ definition.expression }}
                    </a>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ definition.definition }}</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">{{ definition.example }}</small></p>
                {% if definition.tags.all %}
                    {% for tag in definition.tags.all %}
                        <a href="{% url 'tags:tag' tag.slug %}">#{{ tag.tag }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                <hr>
                <button id="button-{{ definition.id }}" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-dark bookmark-btn">
                    {% if not definition.is_bookmarked %}
                        {# Translators: Text for bookmark button. #}
                        {% translate "Add definition to your Bookmarks" %}
                    {% else %}
                        {# Translators: Text for remove bookmark button. #}
                        {% translate "Remove definition from your Bookmarks" %}
                    {% endif %}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        {# Translators: Text for when there are no definitions to display. #}
        <div>{% translate "No definitions." %}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static 'bookmarks/js/bookmark.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi can you add html code as well ? Also you just need to remove `definition` from your bookmark?

Comment: I added my HTML in the question. I should point out that actually this is feed.html and that bookmarks.html {% includes %} this template.

Comment: Hi you need to remove whole div i.e :`<div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">..` ? Sorry i didn't got what you need to remove here can you elaborate :)